# Overlap glyphicons within span

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to overlap two glyphicons to produce a unique image. Classes and format meet Bootstrap 3 standards. Below are demo code and visual output for a single glyphicon:

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span>
  Viruses
  <span class="caret"></span>
</a>
```

[image: single glyphicon visual]

Here's one of my better attempts at combining two glyphicons (demo code and image):

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
  <div style="position: relative; top: 1px; display: inline-block;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk" style="position: absolute !important;"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" style="position: absolute !important;"></span>
  </div>
  Viruses
  <span class="caret"></span>
</a>
```

[image: image of two overlapping glyphicons]

The problem I'm having is that I cannot figure out how to get the stacked glyphicons to match the alignment of the single glyphicon (relative to text). For some reason, the 2 glyphicons are outside the link container. I could potential force the glyphicons to the correct position relative to the link, but if the link container doesn't expand, it will cause spacing issues with other adjacent links.

Additional info: spans assigned glyphicons have the following style properties:

```
.glyphicon {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not add a class to the `a` tag (***parent element***) then wrap the text content (***span tags***) in a ***div*** and place a `display: flex` and `align-items: center` on the `a` tags content,  and then use a selector on the ***icons*** to position its relative content using positions properties, ***top*** and/or ***left***. Also wrap the ***contents*** (***span tags***) in a ***div*** with the class of ***content*** with a ***margin-left*** to place it to the left of the virus icons.

I have BS3 CDN linked with JQuery in the snipit, but the icons are not parsing for some reason, so a bit of tweaking may be needed to the position left/right properties for the ***icons*** element on your end.

Note: I removed all but the position:relative styling from the div element and added classes to the a tag (***icon-parent***) and the div (***icons***)

```css
.icon-parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.icons {
  position: relative;
  top: -6px; /* this may need some tweaking once the icons parse correctly */
  left: 5px;
}

.content {
  margin-left: 2rem; /* this may need some tweaking once the icons parse correctly */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.usebootstrap.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.usebootstrap.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle icon-parent" data-toggle="dropdown">
  <div class="icons">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk" style="position: absolute !important;"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" style="position: absolute !important;"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <span>Viruses</span>
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </div>
</a>
```